# How to create bindings to Shared User Defaults controller from multiple tab views

Tags: swift, cocoa, tabs, preferences

In my app I have a tabbed view to display and manage the preferences. I'd like to store them by using the Shared User Defaults controller. So, I created appropriate bindings through interface builder...Unfortunately, the bindings I create in the first tab work, while the bindings I create in the other tabs don't. The console does not show any erro message, so I don't know where the problem is. Could someone help me understanding what I'm doing wrong, please?

If this can help, I can see that the Shared User Defaults controller is effectively placed in the first tab view scene. I tried moving it to the tabbed view (the one showing the various tab bar items), but if I do that the bindings do not work even in the first tab... So how can I store values through the Shared User Defaults Controller from all the tab view?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say whether this is a bug or the expected behavior. I have found a way to access the Shared User Defaults in multiple tabs of an NSTabView; here's what works for me:

In the NSTabViewController subclass add this:

```
override func viewWillAppear() {  
    super.viewWillAppear()

    // make me the delegate of the Tab View
    tabView.delegate = self

    // give the initially selected tab a reference to the User Defaults
    tabView.selectedTabViewItem?.viewController?.representedObject = UserDefaults.standard
}

override func tabView(_ tabView: NSTabView, didSelect tabViewItem: NSTabViewItem?) {
    super.tabView(tabView, didSelect: tabViewItem)

    // give the newly selected tab a reference to the User Defaults
    tabViewItem?.viewController?.representedObject = UserDefaults.standard
}
```

Then in your bindings in IB, select the tab you are in as the "Bind To" and set the "Model Key Path" to  representedObject.your_default_key. If needed, set the "Value Transformer" appropriately.